# Splitting an array of objects by property

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, properties

What's the best way to chunk an array of objects by a property?

I want the object to work similar to a case statement without a default - where it continues to bubble down.

**Input**

```
[  
   {  
      "type":"Break"
   },
   {  
      "type":"Not Break"
   },
   {  
      "type":"Break"
   },
   {  
      "type":"Not Break"
   },
   {  
      "type":"Break"
   },
   {  
      "type":"Not Break"
   },
   {  
      "type":"Not Break"
   },
   {  
      "type":"Not Break"
   },
   {  
      "type":"Not Break"
   },
   {  
      "type":"Not Break"
   },
   {  
      "type":"Break"
   }
]
```

**Output**

```
[[{"type":"Break"}, {"type":"Not Break"}], [{"type":"Break"}, {"type":"Not Break"}] ...]
```

Thanks,
Ollie

Comment: Hi! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps give `Objec.keys` a try.

```
myInputArray.forEach( myInputObject => {
  Object.keys(myInputObject).forEach( key => {
      if(key === 'type'){
          // Do magic
          // get the content by 
          myInputObject[key]
      }
      if(key === 'otherType'){
          // Do more magic
      }
  })
})
```

Warm regards

Answer (score 0):

You can chunk using [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and pushing a new child array on `Break`. This is making some assumptions (like your first time will be of type `Break`), so you'll need to figure out your edge cases, but it should get you started:

```js
let arr = [ { "type":"Break"},{  "type":"Not Break"},{  "type":"Break"},{  "type":"Not Break"},{  "type":"Break"},{  "type":"Not Break"},{  "type":"Not Break"},{  "type":"Not Break"},{  "type":"Not Break"},{  "type":"Not Break"},{  "type":"Break"}]

 let chunks = arr.reduce((arr, item) => {
    if (item.type == 'Break')  arr.push([])  // create a new child
    arr[arr.length-1].push(item)             // push into last child
    return arr
}, [])
console.log(chunks)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you need to chunk the input data every time the **initial** `type` changes. If that assumption is correct you could do something like this:

```js
var data = [{ "type": "Break" }, { "type": "Not Break" }, { "type": "Break" }, { "type": "Not Break" }, { "type": "Break" }, { "type": "Not Break" }, { "type": "Not Break" }, { "type": "Not Break" }, { "type": "Not Break" }, { "type": "Not Break" }, { "type": "Break" } ]

const result = data.reduce((r,c) => {
  r.length && c.type != r[r.length-1][0].type ? r[r.length-1].push(c) : r.push([c])
  return r
}, [])

console.log(result)
```